# how to interact with google bar chart from h-axis labels

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using google bar charts as a navigational interface to display records with a date range by clicking on the h-axis labels which in my case show month and year.

The problem is that there is no interactivity, eg the cursor changing when you roll over the dates on the h-axis.

I'm accessing the h-axis label using:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (e) {

var bar_date = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#0#label#(\d+)/);
```

This gets me an object from which I obtain the date associated with the bar in the chart.

Can the clicked label on the h-axis be made to change via the same event?

update: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mygene/3pmvydos/) with working example as per accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can certainly change the chart labels.

first, we must differentiate the h-axis labels from the rest of the chart labels.
this can be done by using an attribute on the `<text>` element.
here, the `text-anchor` attribute is used.
when the label is clicked, the color is changed to red.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['date', 'value'],
    [new Date(2019, 0), 2924],
    [new Date(2019, 1), 2075],
    [new Date(2019, 2), 2516],
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (e) {
    var bar_date = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#0#label#(\d+)/);
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var bar_labels = [];

    // get chart labels
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      // find h-axis labels
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        bar_labels.push(label);
      }
    });

    // find label clicked
    if (bar_date) {
      bar_labels[bar_date[1]].setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MM/yy',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

the structure of the data table should not make any difference,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {
        "id": "Month",
        "label": "Month",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "id": "y0",
        "label": "y0",
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "id": "y0",
        "label": "y0",
        "type": "number"
      },
      {
        "id": "y0",
        "label": "y0",
        "type": "number"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [{"c": [{"v": "Sep 2014"}, {"v": 100}, {"v": 0}, {"v": 0}]}]
  });

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function (e) {
    var bar_date = e.targetID.match(/hAxis#0#label#(\d+)/);
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    var bar_labels = [];

    // get chart labels
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      // find h-axis labels
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
        bar_labels.push(label);
      }
    });

    // find label clicked
    if (bar_date) {
      bar_labels[bar_date[1]].setAttribute('fill', '#ff0000');
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MM/yy',
      ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the code WhiteHat, does not work on my chart - maybe because of chart data structure (eg  "rows": [
        {
            "c": [
                {
                    "v": "Sep 2014"
                },
                {
                    "v": 100
                },
                {
                    "v": 0
                },
                {
                    "v": 0
                }
            ] ) , ie c = column and v = value

Comment: thanks again but it still does not work (ie the date does not change color). i note that a console.log of 'labels' = {
    "0": {},
    "1": {},
    "2": {},
    "3": {},
    "4": {},
    "5": {},
    "6": {},
    "7": {},
    "8": {},
    "9": {}, ... } which means is it not picking up the text attribute

Comment: maybe you could edit the question to share the code, works fine above...

Comment: i think its the data structure, pls note there's no "id" {{ "cols": [ { "label": "month", "type": "string" }, { "label": "orange","type": "number"}, {"label": "apple","type": "number"}, {"label": "banana","type": "number"}], "rows": [ {"c": [{ "v": "Sep 2014"}, {"v": 100}, { "v": 0},{"v": 0}]},

Comment: also i am initialising chart differently:google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawColColors);
function drawColColors() {  
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);
   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0,1]);

Comment: Not the structure, once the data table is created, it's all the same, regardless of how it was created.

Comment: It would help if you could edit the question with the code, rather than adding to a comment, please share the code that creates the chart, what type of chart is it? Any errors in the console?

Comment: thanks whitehat I've accepted your answer, a further question: how would you reset the h-axis 'bar_date' color each time?

Comment: not exactly sure what you mean, you could save a reference to the label, if you wanted to change the color later, or just re-draw the chart...